# Implement oAuth2 Authentication in an Outlook Addin

Tags: oauth-2.0, outlook, azure-active-directory

I'm working on an outlook addin that will essentially perform api queries against a protected API. The protected API requires authentication via oAuth2 and Azure Active Directory, with 2FA in place. What I would like to do is have a button that will open a window where users can login with their credentials. Alternatively, a window that redirects them to authentication. I would then like to retrieve the access token to use as a bearer token for API requests.

How would I be able to perform this authentication process and retrieve the access token?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using the following code

```
 AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authorityUri);

        var result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(serverUri, clientId, new Uri(clientUri), new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Auto));
```

var _accessToken = result.AccessToken to get the access token

Comment: It's great you figured this out. Can you paste the code instead of a screenshot of the code?